# how to develop User friendly url in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

how to develop User friendly URLs in salesforce and while clicking on this it should redirect to that particular visual force page.

please consider below sample

https://force.site.com/ramesh-amaravadi/loacation/id

Comment: Do you need any parameters to be sent on another page or just need to redirect on a static page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use button/link to redirect user to VF

Also in page layout you can use Formula field to build HYPERLINK.

```
    HYPERLINK Creates a link to a URL specified that is linkable from the text specified.
```

In that case you will need atlest 1 additional field to keep url and other for link name( if for all records values will be same you can use labels)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[Site.UrlRewriter](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm)** interface to clean them up. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this inside SFDC or for external facing pages? If that's the case, I don't believe it's actually possible

For external facing pages (site.com, community, etc), you should be able to easily implement [Site.UrlRewriter](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm)